# Todoist Login Failure During OAuth Authorization in React Native App

Tags: react-native, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, todoist

I'm developing a Todoist clone using React Native and have integrated their Sync API for adding, deleting, updating, and completing tasks. However, I'm encountering an authorization problem during the OAuth flow in mobile but in chrome it is working completely fine i am using WebView component. steps for Authorization: https://developer.todoist.com/guides/#authorization.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Initiate the authorization process by making an API call to `https://todoist.com/oauth/authorize` with required parameters like client_id, scope, and state.
   you can try it out : https://todoist.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=d09c02e277a74b8d9c2c48bddd99afaa&scope=data:read_write&state=1710218121052 (in chrome it is working as expected but with mobile app it would be redirect with login screen).
2. I'm redirected to the [TODOIST login screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXwwH.png)
3. Upon entering valid credentials (verified elsewhere), I receive an "Invalid email or password" error.

**Questions:**

- Are there any specific requirements or considerations for using Todoist's OAuth flow within a React Native app?
- Could any configuration issues in my Todoist app integration or code might be causing the login failure?

**What I've Tried:**

- Double-checked the validity of the credentials I'm using (e.g., by logging in directly to Todoist with the same credentials).
- Verified that the redirect URI in my code matches the one configured in the Todoist developer console.

**Expected Behavior:**

- The login should be successful using the provided credentials, granting access to the Todoist API for authorized operations after successful login it should be displayed [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6NUC.png).

Any suggestions would be appreciated :)